# Select "other" from the selectbox and activate textfield

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, xhtml, html4

I have a question based on my selectbox:

```
     <select name="Companies" id="Companies">
         <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
         <option value="AB-CityNY">AB, New York</option>
         <option value="AB-CityWAS">AB, Washington</option>
         <option value="AB-CityLON">AB, London</option>
         <option value="CD-CityStockholm">CD, Stockholm</option>
         <option value="EF-CityBerlin">Rome Company, North</option>
         <option value="EF-CityRome">Rome Company, South</option>
         <option value="GH-CityMadrid">Madrid Company</option>
         <option value="Other">Fill out the textfield</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" name="ActivateOther" size="25" class="required" />
```

Of course I need all information posted to my next page (which is in ASP Classic) no matter if it is from the selectbox or textfield, but it is also okay if the selectbox sends the option-value to the "ActivateOther"-textfield, so I only have one field to work with on the next page. The page already has jQuery in use.

Comment: Can you simplify your statement _but it is also okay if the selectbox sends the option-value to the "ActivateOther"-textfield, so I only have one field to work with on the next page._?

Comment: Do you want to autofill the ActivateOther textbox when other option is selected?

Comment: I only want the textfield "ActivateOther" to be activated when "Other" is selected among the options...else it should be readonly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying to answer my question. I found this to be the solution to my question (even though there is no read-only solution):

**[Show a text field on a specific option select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131049/show-a-text-field-on-a-specific-option-select)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. this might work

```
$("#Companies").change(function(){
    if ($("#Companies").val() == "Other") {
        $("#ActivateOther").focus();
    }
})
```

Comment: If I put that into a <script>-tag above the selectbox, then it will still yield the same result as before. The textfield isn't readonly when any of the options are marked.